# How to handle return null with custom exception

Tags: java, appium

For the below code `getDriver()` method is asking to return null by default. Can we handle it with a custom exception?

```
public AppiumDriver<WebElement> getDriver() {

    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", TestConstants.appPath);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", TestConstants.deviceName);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appPackage", TestConstants.appPackage);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity", TestConstants.appActivity);
    try {

        AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
        driver.resetApp();
        return driver;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error is -  " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) do not `catch` the exception inside the method (declare the method with `throws`); or 2) throw a new (or same) exception, e.g. `throw new MyException(...)` (or `throw e`) - also requires the method to `throws MyException`

Comment: Able to throw Exception. Can you please help me with a snippet for sample custom throws an exception?

Comment: `public void test() throws MyException { if (...) throw new MyException("message"); }` and somewhere `public class MyException extends Exception { ...}` (or use one of the standard exceptions if one fit (e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`)

Answer (score 0):

This method will not be compiled since there is a branch without returning expression (in catch).

To fix that you can just add `return null` as the last line in the catch block to meet the expectations.